# Separating Python dictionaries and lists in a PyQGIS plugin

Tags: qgis-plugins

I am new to Python and QGIS Plugin development
I am trying to write a plugin which will reference some dictionaries and lists that I would like to keep outside of the main module in a separate '.py' file as they are used by both the Dialog and the main module.
I'm having trouble working out what the separate module should look like and how to call it in either the MyPluginName_dialog.py or MyPluginName.py

Separate.py looks like this:

```
def get_the_Dictionary():
    # Return a dictionary of all things
    AllThings= {'A_THING':['300','AT'],'ANOTHER_THING':['301','AG']}
    return AllThings
```

To include the dictionary in MyPluginName.py I've tried:

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QSettings, QTranslator, QCoreApplication
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import QIcon
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QAction

# Initialize Qt resources from file resources.py
from .resources import *
# Import the code for the dialog
from .MyPluginName_dialog import MyPluginNameDialog
import os.path
from .Separate import *
```

The plugin reloader returns a Module Not found error.

Note that all the .py files are under the same directory built by plugin builder e.g.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Name the file lowercase `separate.py` and then use `from .seperate import *`